# get name of function passed as argument to parent function

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

given the code below, how do I print the name of child process that was passed in as the `self.looper(_function=)` argument? I have no idea how to do this! I am trying to do logic based on which function was passed into `_function`. Hope I conveyed the question correctly. thanks!!

```
class okheregoes(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def looper(self, _function):
        print('the function name that was passed to _function is {}'.format(_function.__name__))
        if _function.__name__ == 'child1':
            print('it was child 1 this time')
        if _function.__name__ == 'child2':
            print('it was child 2 this time')



    def child1(self, _number):
        return 'my favorite number is {}'.format(_number)

    def child2(self, _number):
        return 'my favorite number is {}'.format(_number)

    def main(self):
        for i in range(1,10):
            self.looper(_function=self.child1(_number=i+1))
            self.looper(_function=self.child2(_number=i-1))





pleashelp = okheregoes()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pleashelp.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `wtfisthis` with `_function.__name__`

Please note that you are passing a string and not a function to self.dictlooper. To fix this, define child1 and child2 like this:

```
def child1(self, _number):
    def inner():
        return 'my favorite number is {}'.format(_number)
    return inner
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing functions or child processes to `dictlooper`. (You're not even using child processes.) You're passing strings. Those strings were returned by functions named `child1` and `child2`, but Python keeps no record of what functions a string has been in.

There is nothing you could put in place of `wtfisthis` to get the function name information. You would have to change the rest of your code, perhaps by actually passing functions around.

Comment: clearly I dont know what I'm doing which is why I am posting this here. I did a mockup of this problem as best I could without posting my actual source code i'm working with. I will try to make a better example so I can show you why I am trying to figure out how to get the parent function name.